# Heroku local command not working: /bin/sh: python: command not found

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to use `heroku local` to run my heroku application but whenever I run `heroku local`, I get the following error:

```
$heroku local
9:58:47 AM web.1 |  /bin/sh: python: command not found
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
9:58:47 AM web.1 Exited with exit code null
```

I am wondering if the issue is that I have python3 installed and not python, because when I run `which python3` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
```

However, when I run `which python` I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don’t have a command named `python` on your system. Change your `Procfile` to `python3` instead.